# How to change output format in lambda output

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J7VD.jpg)Im very new to the concepts DynamoDB and Lambda. I've created a table in DynamoDB:

[image]

and got the item from dynamodb table to lambda using primary key using python. The output is:

```
{'id': 'ABC' , 'Data': 'a,b,c,d'}
```

[image]

Now in the Data variable, the data is comma-separated and I need the data without commas like:

```
{'id': 'ABC' , 'Data': 'a b c d'}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please show us the code in your AWS Lambda function.

Comment: import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

def lambda_handler(event, context):
 
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    client = boto3.client("dynamodb")
    table = dynamodb.Table('Test')

    response=table.get_item(
       Key={
           'id': 'ABC'
           }
        )
 
    print(response['Item'])

Comment: Please put your code in your Question rather than in a comment. You could modify your Python code to take the returned data and remove the commas (eg `response['Item']['Data'] = response['Item']['Data'].replace(",", " ")`).

Comment: Thank you John. It worked. It is my first time using stack overflow. From next time I will post the questions properly.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with DynamoDB or Lambda.. You need to write logic once you get the output.

Comment: can you please help me with the logic then?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your Python code to take the returned data and remove the commas.

For example:

```
response['Item']['Data'] = response['Item']['Data'].replace(",", " "))
```

This will replace any commas with spaces.